# Как продолжить цикл, с того место где вышло исключение?Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, исключения, циклы

В цикле перебираю ip и useragent для парсинга сайта, некоторые из ip не отвечают и после этого выходит исключение, и цикл идёт дальше, так вот, как сделать так чтобы после исключения он не продолжал дальше, пропуская то место где вышло исключение, а снова стартовал с того места где вышло исключение, но уже с другим ip, т.к иначе он пропускает страницу.

```
def main():

    url = 'http://old.toto-info.co/DataService.svc/GetMaxPrizeCoupons'
    useragents = open("useragents.txt").read().split('\n')
    proxies = open("proxies.txt").read().split('\n')

    for i in range(0,200,20):
        try:
            a = (uniform(1, 2))
            sleep(a)
            StartFroms = i
            useragent = "'" + choice(useragents) + "'"
            proxy = {'http': 'http://' + choice(proxies)}
            get_html(url,useragent,proxy,StartFroms)
        except:
            print("not working")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно в случае возникновения исключения запускать цикл `for` с той точки, где оно возникло:

```
start = 0  # переменная для хранения точки входа в for  
while start < finish:
   try:
      for i in range(start, finish, step):
         do_something()
         if i >= finish - step:
            start = finish  # для выхода из внешнего цикла
      except:
         start = i  # перезапускаем for c точки исключения
```

Пример:

```
from random import randint

start = 0
finish = 4
while start < finish:
    try:
        for i in range(start, finish):
            print i
            if randint(0, 1):
                raise ValueError(i)
            if i >= finish - 1:
                start = finish
    except ValueError as e:
        print "exception:", e
        start = i
```

Вывод:

```
D:\Python\python.exe D:/PycharmProjects/tl/aa.py
0
exception: 0
0
exception: 0
0
1
2
3
exception: 3
3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: не, не сработало @andy.37

Comment: @ПашаВасильев Что значит "не сработало"? Я там добавил учловие корректного выхода из цикла и пример

Comment: @ПашаВасильев, сорри, конечно было неправильно, поправил

Comment: Извиняюсь, не сразу заметил, что изменилось, всё работает как надо теперь@andy.37

Comment: @ПашаВасильев, да я сам поспешил, так чтто скорее я должен извиняться :)

Answer (score 0):

или воспользоватся рекурсией

```
def main(_i=0):
    for i in range(_i,200,20):
        try:
            pass
        except:
            return main(i)  # продолжить с ошибочного индекса
```

или

```
def proxy_get_html(url, useragent, StartFroms):
    proxy = {'http': 'http://' + choice(proxies)}
    try: get_html(url, useragent, proxy, StartFroms)
    except: return proxy_get_html(url, useragent, StartFroms)
    else: return True

def main():
    for i in range(0,200,20):
        proxy_get_html(url, useragent, proxy, StartFroms)
```